# What is the maximum amount of diamonds in one vein?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Recently I have started a survival world on Xbox 360. I immediately found a cave with around 24 diamonds. It was in a odd location with a 1 by 1 hole leading to the cave. It also had a dirt pillar that was about 10 dirt blocks high. This was kind of suspecting that somebody did it because I was in creative earlier and I left to do something. So I was wondering what the maximum amount of diamonds were possible or if that was just a person who placed it.

Comment: I haven't played in years, but the max in one vein used to be 8. However, multiple veins could spawn adjacent.

Comment: There is only one diamond vein possible within a chunk. So no chance of multiple veins

Comment: @Fennekin Completely untrue. I've had 5 veins in a single chunk before, and I'd imagine that even more are possible. Even if it were true, 4 veins could still all spawn joined together at the corners of their chunks.

Comment: Wait a minute. Correct me if I am wrong, I think vein consist (2-8) blocks of diamond. And as far as I know there is only one vein(blocks of diamonds) in one chunk.

Comment: @Fennekin I forgot to add this part but it was in a ravine and 5 blocks away on the other side of the ravine were 2 separate veins with like 3 in one and 2 in the other. So is this also possible?

Comment: @Mr.Advice  now that you mention it that it was a ravine. Now I can assume that there were 2 chunks(since ravine is across many chunks and chunk is just 16 by 16 area). So it is possible to have 2 group of diamond blocks near by. But I know that there may not be more than one group of diamond blocks within a chunk.

Comment: @Fennekin so could it be possible that it was the corner of 4 different chunks. Since there was one big vein on one side which could be two chunks together and two separate veins close by which is the other two chunks

Comment: @Mr.Advice Possible! But very rare.I mean all diamonds exposed to surface. Well there is something I want to ask is there multiplayer option in xbox360?

Comment: @Fennekin there is. Does it really make a difference in world generation though?

Comment: @Mr.Advice  no multiplayer does not affect world generation. I was asking "**have you connected to a multiplayer server?**" Because there is possibility that a player in that server must have done that.

Comment: @Fennekin I mean it is.

Answer (score 11):

Diamond ore appears in veins of 3-8. As said by the Minecraft wiki and also by personal experience.

> Diamond ore only appears at Y level 16 and below, and can be found in veins of 3–8.

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore)

Comment: Minecraft generates 1 vein per chunk, but doesn't look at other chunks when doing so, so it is theoretically possible (but extremely unlikely) to find a "megavein" of 32 diamonds comprised of 4 adjacent 8-diamond veins on a chunk crossing. It's much more common to find 9-10 diamond "veins" as, say, a 4-diamond and a 6-diamond vein align along a chunk border.

Answer (score 2):

Due to how Minecraft vein generation works, it is possible to find veins with up to 10 diamonds even though the max vein size is 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think the max is 10 because I found 10 in one vein and no one else other than me had access to my world on this seed, and I never went on creative on it before. It’s seed 777, Position: -1264, 10, 387

Answer (score 0):

As the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore) stated in Meantub's answer:

> Diamond ore attempts to generate 1 time per chunk in **veins of 0-10
> ore**, in layers 1 to 16 in all biomes.

But, it is possible to find a much larger diamond vein than this, if multiple veins spawn directly beside each other on different chunks. This could result in a maximum of 40 diamonds in a single *giant vein*, if the veins generated in corners. But, this is highly unlikely to ever occur in game.